# Finding the max value in an array

Tags: c#, arrays

As part of school, one of my assignments is to write 10 pieces of code about 10 different search patterns, etc.

For this one, i need to use a linear search to find the highest and lowest value in a defined array, and then display the number of times that value was found.

Heres the code i came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Maxvaluefinder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var array = [1, 31, 10, 9, 420, -5, 77, 420, 300, 99]; //Sets up the array
            var maxvalue = 0; //Establishes variables for maximum value and the counter of maximum value.
            var maxvaluecount = 0;

            for (i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] > maxvalue)
                {
                    maxvalue = array[i];
                    maxvaluecount = 1;
                }
                if (array[i] == maxvalue)
                {
                     maxvaluecount = maxvaluecount + 1;
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("The highest number in this array was" + maxvalue + "which appeared a total of" + maxvaluecount + "times."); // Prints the final outcome.
        }
    }
}
```

**As of now, i am not 100% sure how the "for (i = 1; i < intArray.Length; i++)"
part works, and the 'i' bits 'do not exist in current context'**

Please help?

Also, somewhat unrelated: how do i test run the code in microsoft visual studio?

Thanks :)

Comment: Your second question: press F5.  And, by the way, array indexes start at zero, so you want `for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)` . Or you can go for `foreach (var i in array)` if you'd rather.

Comment: @O.Jones: One should of course create a C# console project first and put this code into a file in said project.

Comment: Probably not what your teacher was going for, but there is also just `array.Max()`....

Comment: `array.Max()` does indeed use a linear search.

Comment: Note that array.Max is from `IEnumerable<T>` (LINQ) so it works for *any* collection, and takes a selector method if need be. Good stuff to know when the functionality to implement isn't so contrived :)

Answer (score 1):

1st question: You need to declare your `i` inside `for` loop if you only want to use `i` inside it. Otherwise you need to declare `i` before the `for` loop.

```
for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
```

And this is how you create new `int` array

```
var array = new int[] { 1, 31, 10, 9, 420, -5, 77, 420, 300, 99};
```

2nd question: Go to VS, create new console project, paste your code under `main` function and press F5

Comment: i'd suggest change _You need to declare your `i` inside for loop_ **to** -->  _you  should declare your `i` inside the for loop_

Comment: wow, that was simple. thanks! Uh, one last thing though, the line  "var array = [1, 31, 10, 9, 420, -5, 77, 420, 300, 99]; //Sets up the array"  is causing an error at the first [ . Any idea why? :p (line 13)

Comment: thanks. this is also my first time on stack overflow if you didnt guess :)

Comment: why do you have `i` starting at `1` and not `0`? This answer ignores the first item in the array...

Comment: @RufusL is correct however i would assume OP meant to replace this variable -->  `var maxvalue = 0;` with this -->  `var maxvalue = array[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a variable before you can use it. Try:

```
for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++){...}
```

A for loop works as follows:

1. You declare a control variable, in this case *i*, you assign it the starting value 1.
2. The for loop checks at the start of each loop if its end condition is satisfied, in the given case `i < array.Length`
3. At the end of every loop, the control variable gets updated according to the last part of your syntax `i++`, which is equivalent to `i = i+1`

Also, I am not sure if you knew that, but in C# arrays are zero-based indexed, which means, that the first element in an array has actually the index zero. So you probably want to initialize: `int i = 0`

Comment: why do you have `i` starting at `1` and not `0`? This answer ignores the first item in the array...

Comment: Because his example had it at 1. I haven't looked into the semantics, just the syntax. I will add a reminder though.

Comment: Yeah, but his original code was incorrect. The question is about finding the max value in an array, and your answer ignores the first item. Why not just post the correct solution?